# How to make the Textbox field accept only Decimal Values in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to make the Textbox field accept only Decimal Values

Answer (score 2):

Can use...
http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        function is_int(test) 
            typeof (a = (typeof test == "function" ? test() : test)) == "number" ? !(a % 1) : false;



returns:

is_int(8) // true

is_int("8") // false

function test() {   
        return 12
}

is_int(test()) // true
```